# how to add sub array in main array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

```
{
    "firstName": "AA",
    "lastName": "BB,
    "shortName": "CC",
    "nric": "12/AAA(N)123456",
    "gender": "F",
    "dob": "1.1.2000",
    "password": "admin123",
    "photo": {
        "image": "hello",
        "thumb": "world"
    }
}
```

Is there anyway how to add photo array in main array? I've done as follow

```
let photoArray = [
    "image": imageBase64,
    "thumb": imageBase64
]

let param = [
    "firstName": txtFirstName.text as! AnyObject,
    "lastName": txtLastName.text as! AnyObject,
    "shortName": txtShortName.text as! AnyObject,
    "nric":"",
    "gender": genderCode,
    "dob":txtDOB.text as! AnyObject,
    "photo": photoArray
]
```

but output is awful. Please let me how to do it.

Comment: Array or Dictionary?

Comment: you are making a dictionary not an array

Comment: @BhumitMehta dictionary instead

Comment: please let me know how to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making the param `let` make it `var` and do the following. You do need to specify the dictionary type as below

```
let photoArray : [String : AnyObject] = [
            "pic" : "myPhoto"
        ]
var param : [String : AnyObject] = [
            "name" : "UserName"
        ]

param["photo"] = photoArray
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    let photoArray = [[
        "image": "a",
        "thumb": "b"],[
            "image": "a",
            "thumb": "b"]
    ]
let param = [
"firstName": txtFirstName.text as! AnyObject,
"lastName": txtLastName.text as! AnyObject,
"shortName": txtShortName.text as! AnyObject,
"nric":"",
"gender": genderCode,
"dob":txtDOB.text as! AnyObject,
"photo": photoArray
```

]

Hope you want like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
let photoArray:[String:UIImage] = [
    "image": UIImage.init(named: "a.png")!,
    "thumb": UIImage.init(named: "b.png")!
]

let param:[String:AnyObject] = [
    "firstName": "AA",
    "lastName": "BB",
    "shortName": "CC",
    "nric": "",
    "gender": 0,
    "dob": "DD",
    "photo": photoArray
]
```

You can do it like this